# How can I best build up and edit XML in my Java app

Tags: java, xml, stax, dom4j

I need to create some XML programmatically, sometimes with programming calls, sometimes starting by reading in some XML (a string) and then revising it with calls. And then write the XML out to a stream.

The writing out I assume is best done with codehaus stax (if there's a newer way, please tell me what). But for the rest, at present I am using dom4j and that is old and abandoned. So I need to upgrade to something that is supported and has no security issues.

Is there something in the Java runtime? Or is there a commonly used library?

We are on Java 1.8 so a solution cannot require 1.9 or later.

Comment: Jackson has xml capabilities

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options here.

## Parsers

Parsers take the whole document (SAX parsed is exception here) and create a tree structure from some common classes like `Document`, `Node` etc.. You can load any XML and work with it. No need to have some class that would represent the file.

### Pros

- you can load any file
- you have the power of all the standard XML tooling, like XSLT transformations, xpath, etc..

### Cons

- hard to create new file programaticaly
- harder to extract info from it

### Tools

- [DOM Parsers](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)
- SAX Parser

## Object serialization

Second approach you can take is by Object parsing. You basically have a class that represents you data structure and you serialize it to/from XML.

### Pros

- super easy to use
- fast to just read/write data from existing data structures

### Cons

- not easy to use XSLT, etc..
- cannot really read random XML files

### Tools

- JAXB
- XStream
- Jackson